# Hyperledger fabric client credential store using CouchDB

Tags: yaml, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am using Hyperledger Fabric SDK for node.js to enroll a user. I am using [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/balance-transfer) code to deploy in fabric. It uses FileKeyValueStore (uses files to store the key values) to store client's user credential. 
I want to use CouchDBKeyValueStore to store user key in CouchDB database instance. What changes do i need to make in client connection profile configuration file for credential store and in code to do so. Any link to sample code will also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in support in the connection profile for using the `CouchDBKeyValueStore`, but you can still use the connection profile for the rest of the Fabric network configuration.  You'll then need to use the Client APIs to configure the stores.  Something like

```
const Client = require('fabric-client');
const CDBKVS = require('fabric-client/lib/impl/CouchDBKeyValueStore.js');

var client = Client.loadFromConfig('test/fixtures/network.yaml');

// Set the state store
let stateStore = await new CDBKVS({url: 'https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<URL>', name: '<DB_NAME>'})
client.setStateStore(stateStore);

// Set the crypto store
const crypto = Client.newCryptoSuite();
let cryptoKS = Client.newCryptoKeyStore(
    CDBKVS,
    {
      url: 'https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<URL>.cloudant.com',
      name: '<DB_NAME>'
    }
);
crypto.setCryptoKeyStore(cryptoKS);
client.setCryptoSuite(crypto);
```

---

Official document Reference
[Store Hyperledger Fabric certificates and keys in IBM Cloudant with Fabric Node SDK](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/store-fabric-certificates-keys-ibm-cloudant-fabric-node-sdk/)