# Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Hey I have  working on hyper ledger fabric from last 1 and half month and I am using fabcar sample network, I want to save the wallet information in couch db instead of system storage but I am not able to find the URL for connecting couch db. Can any one suggest something, either solution or right method to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CouchDBWallet class to store your identity into couchdb.

For more info: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/CouchDBWallet.html

Also there is another way: [Hyperledger fabric client credential store using CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305378/hyperledger-fabric-client-credential-store-using-couchdb)

Comment: I have used CouchDBwallet class and CouchDbKeyValue class for storing wallet details in the couch db but I am not getting the couch db address to put it as argument in  CouchDBWallet.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be aware that the Wallet implementation in the SDK is changing for Fabric 2.0.  There is a Jira explaining the changes [here](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-1353) with a Presentation attached, and there is some documentation [here](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/tutorial-wallet.html).

There was a presentation on the Fabric Application Developers Community Call, and the recording download is [here](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/download/attachments/6423554/2019-1003-fabricdevcommunitycall.zip).